# Java: Inheritance: **The issue I am having is with public class DocumentDemo

Tags: java

The problem I am having is with public class DocumentDemo...It is telling me "The method ContainsKeyword cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type" for the boolean part.
Also, it is telling me the same for the public static void main.  Same error message.  I feel there is a easy fix but cannot find it, any help would be awesome.

```
public class Document {

    private String text;

    public Document(){
        text = "";
    }

    public Document(String text){
        this.text = text;   
}

    public String toString(){

        return text;
    }

public class Email extends Document{
    private String sender;
    private String recipient;
    private String title;

    public Email(String body, String sender, String recipient, String title){
        super(body);
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.title = title;

    }

    public String getSender(){
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(){
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getRecipient(){
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(){
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Sender " + sender + " Recipient " + recipient + " Title " + title + " " + super.toString();
    }

public class File extends Document{
    private String pathname;

    public File(){
        super(); 
        pathname = " ";
    }

    public File(String body, String pathname){
        super(body);
        this.pathname = pathname;
    }

    public String getPathname(){
        return pathname;
    }

    public void setPathname(String S){
        pathname = S;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Pathname" + pathname + " body " + super.toString();
    }




public class DocumentDemo{

    public static boolean ContainsKeyword(Document docObject, String keyword){
        if(docObject.toString().indexOf(keyword, 0) >= 0)
            return true;
        else
        return false;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){

        Email e1 = new Email("I am not sure if this is working", "Jarvis", "Professor", "An attempt at Programming in Java.");
        Email e2 = new Email("Please let this work", "Jarvis", "My Family", "I am feel lost, but I understand the concept");

        File f1 = new File("IT 2650, Java", "file.txt");
        File f2 = new File("Getting By", "file.txt");

        System.out.println("Which one contains the word Java?");
        if(ContainsKeyword(e1, "Java"))
            System.out.println("Email 1");
        if(ContainsKeyword(e2, "Java"))
            System.out.println("Email 2");
        if(ContainsKeyword(f1, "Java"))
            System.out.println("File 1");
        if(ContainsKeyword(f2, "Java"))
            System.out.println("File 2");
    }
}



}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentDemo` is nested inside the `Document` class. You need to mark it `static` or move it to its own file. Also, fix your indentation, and you should probably split some or all of these classes out into separate files.

Comment: I fixed a few things to include the static part and an extra bracket but now on new Email I get an error.     "Error: Main method not found in class Document, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
"   What else am I missing here.  I never separated files so I could try that but not sure how to move forward there.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your classes inside your `Document` class because you forgot to close its ending bracket.